# How can I determine a specific level in a parent/child-array?

Tags: php, treeview

I am looping over an array of groups, each element containing a parent id.

```
$currentparent = $group['grpId']; //$group is the current element in a loop wrapped around this piece of code
$currentlevel = 0;

foreach($groups as $grp)
{
    $parent = $grp['grpParentId'];

    if($parent != $currentparent && $currentlevel != 6)
    {
        //adding layer
        $currentlevel++;
        //changing parent
        $currentparent = $grp['grpParentId'];
    }

    if($currentlevel == 6)
    {
        //call a special function
    }
    else
    {
        //call the regular function
    }
}
```

This works fine on a array like this:

```
group
-group
--group
---group
----group
----- group <- the only group on the 5th layer
```

but not with an array which has multiple groups on the 5th level:

```
group
-group
--group
--group
---group
----group
-----group <- 5th layer
----group
-----group <- 5th layer too, but diff parent
```

How can I resolve this to get the special function called, even when there are multiple groups with multiple parents on the fifth level in the array?

I hope that I formulated my question clear enough.

Comment: Will the special function always be done only on the 1st 5th layer group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating trough the the groups always searching for groups whose level can be determinated by its parent level. Something like this:

```
// example input
$groups = array(
    array('grpParentId' => 0, 'grpId' => 1, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 1, 'grpId' => 2, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 2, 'grpId' => 3, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 3, 'grpId' => 4, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 4, 'grpId' => 5, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 5, 'grpId' => 6, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 6, 'grpId' => 7, ),

    array('grpParentId' => 5, 'grpId' => 8, ),
    array('grpParentId' => 8, 'grpId' => 9, ),
);


shuffle($groups); // just for testing the logic does in fact tolerate randomly ordered input

$rootId = 1; // set to the rootnode's id
$grouplevels = array();

// find the rootnode first
foreach($groups as $i => $grp) {
    if ($rootId == $grp['grpId']) {
        $grouplevels[$rootId] = 1;
        unset($groups[$i]);
        break;
    }
}

// figure out childgroup levels
do {
    $old_count = count($groups);
    foreach($groups as $i => $grp) {
        if (in_array($grp['grpParentId'], array_keys($grouplevels))) {
            // the current node's parent's level was determinated previously, we can tell this group's level as well
            $grouplevels[$grp['grpId']] = $level = $grouplevels[$grp['grpParentId']]+1;

            if ($level == 6) {
                print $grp['grpId']."\n";
            }

            // remove from the "we dont know yet" list
            unset($groups[$i]);
        }
    }
} while (count($groups) < $old_count); // run while we can sort out at least one group's level in the current iteration

// handle the case when not every group's level could been determinated!
if (!empty($groups)) {
    print "inconsitency ahead!";
}
```

Comment: The parent id's do not increment equally with 1, because the group structure can be edited. (so it can be "28->23->14->36" instead of just "1->2->3->4"

Comment: @ErikKlop: I've updated the code's logic to work with random input too.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using a recursive pattern. The following code should do the trick. It can probably be optimized.

```
$currentparent = $group['grpId']; //$group is the current element in a loop wrapped around         
$this piece of code
$currentlevel = 0;

// Initialize 
foreach($groups as $grp)
{
    $grp['children'] = array();

}

foreach($groups as $grp)
{
    $parent = $grp['grpParentId'];
    $parent['children'][] = $grp;  
}

foreach($groups as $grp)
{
    if(empty($parent['children'])) $root = $grp; // Alternatively check if parent is null or something. 
}


function recursive_count($root, $lvl = 0)
{
    if($currentlevel == 6)
    {
        //call a special function
    }
    else
    {
        //call the regular function
    }
    foreach($root['children'] as $children)
    {
       recursive_count($children, $lvl++);
    }


 }

 recursive_count($root);
```

**Update:** If memory consumption is a problem references can be used when adding a group to the children array.

**Update II:** Even though the algorithm has 4 foreach and a recursive structure the running time is still O(n) where n is the size of the graph.

Comment: Where would you call recursive_count for the first time?

Comment: Right after the declaration, which i would move in the production code. I'm updating the code now.